# Error: 910 i.e. Syntax error is returned by math.evalStr() API of TI-Nspire engine

Tags: lua, ti-nspire

## Code

I have this Lua script for a TI-Nspire CAS calculator.

```lua
platform.apilevel = '2.2'

box_prompt, error = D2Editor.newRichText():resize(300, 40)
box_prompt:move(0, 0):setBorder(1):setBorderColor(0x43adee):setFontSize(12):setReadOnly(true):setSelectable(false)
    :setTextColor(0x666666):setVisible(true)
result, error = box_prompt:setText('Please enter an expression in box below')

box_expr, error = D2Editor.newRichText():resize(300, 40)
box_expr:move(0, 50):setBorder(1):setBorderColor(0x43adee):setFontSize(12):setReadOnly(false):setSelectable(true)
    :setTextColor(0x000000):setVisible(true)

box_result, error = D2Editor.newRichText():resize(300, 40)
box_result:move(0, 100):setBorder(1):setBorderColor(0x43adee):setFontSize(12):setReadOnly(false):setSelectable(true)
    :setTextColor(0x000000):setVisible(true)

box_expr_doublecheck, error = D2Editor.newRichText():resize(300, 40)
box_expr_doublecheck:move(0, 150):setBorder(1):setBorderColor(0x43adee):setFontSize(12):setReadOnly(true):setSelectable(
    false):setTextColor(0x666666):setVisible(true)

-- To evaluate the expression
function run()
    local expression = box_expr:getExpression()
    box_expr_doublecheck:setText("expression doublecheck: "..expression)
    local result, err = math.evalStr(expression)
    if err ~= nil then
        show_error(err)
        return
    end
    box_result:setText("Result: " .. result)
end

function on.escapeKey()
    run()
end

function show_error(err)
    if err == nil then
    else
        box_result:setText("Error: " .. err)
    end
end
```

## UI

It has four *rich text* boxes.

1. The 1st box is just a read-only help.
2. The 2nd box is where user enters a mathematical expression.
3. The 3rd box will display result or error.
4. The 4th box will display the expression entered by the user to double-check.

[image: Screenshot: before user enters]

## Good expressions

When user enters expressions containing straightforward characters like `-`, `+`, `/`, `*`, `^` then the program works just fine:

[image: Screenshot: good expression]

[image: Screenshot: good expression result]

## Bad expression

However, when user employs the TI-Nspire temlates like *power* and *division* templates, then an `Error: 910` is thrown which according to [Error_Codes](https://education.ti.com/html/webhelp/eg_tinspire/en/Subsystems/EG_RefGuide_CAS/Content/M_RefGuide/RG_Error_Codes_and_Messages.HTML) means `Syntax error`.

[image: Screenshot: bad expression]

[image: Screenshot: bad expression error]

## Template

By tempalte, I mean buttons like these on a TI-Nspire calculator:

[image: Template buttons]

## Question

How can I correctly evaluate an expression that contains one or more TI-Nspire template? I played around with `math.evalStr()`, `math.eval()` and other APIs, but I couldn't figure it out. Thanks.

## UPDATE: `createMathBox()`

I created a *math box* inside the *rich text editor* by this statement: `box_expr:createMathBox()`. Then, any text entered by the user inside that *math box*, even ordinaly `2+3`, throws the syntax error above.

[image: Screenshot: math box]

## UPDATE: doc

[Lua Scripting API Reference Guide](https://education.ti.com/html/webhelp/EG_TINspireLUA/EN/content/libraries/2deditorlib/2deditorlibrary.htm)  provides a table with more information about annotations in proprietary markup language:

[image: Doc]

Comment: What is returned in `local expression = box_expr:getExpression()` when you entered the expression 1+3<sup>2</sup> ?

Comment: @ESkri The same error is received: `Error: 910`

Comment: @ESkri I doublechecked the returned value of `local expression = box_expr:getExpression()` and I observe that it is: `1+3<sup>2</sup>`

Comment: So, `getExpression` returns valid html code?  What is returned for other "templates"?  What is returned from rich text editor?

Comment: @ESkri I believe a posted screenshot gives an example of how a *template* is returned. The returned text is dispalyed by *expression doublecheck* field on the screenshot.

Comment: Obviously, `math.evalStr` does not support the format returned by `getExpression`.  You should parse it yourself or find some API function to do it for you.  BTW, your links to education.ti.com website are "Access Denied" for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fixed code:

```lua
platform.apilevel = '2.2'

box_prompt, error = D2Editor.newRichText():resize(300, 40)
box_prompt:move(0, 0):setBorder(1):setBorderColor(0x43adee):setFontSize(12):setReadOnly(true):setSelectable(false)
    :setTextColor(0x666666):setVisible(true)
result, error = box_prompt:setText('Please enter an expression in box below')

box_expr, error = D2Editor.newRichText():resize(300, 40)
box_expr:move(0, 50):setBorder(1):setBorderColor(0x43adee):setFontSize(12):setReadOnly(false):setSelectable(true)
    :setTextColor(0x000000):setVisible(true)
matbox = box_expr:createMathBox() -- Math Box

box_result, error = D2Editor.newRichText():resize(300, 40)
box_result:move(0, 100):setBorder(1):setBorderColor(0x43adee):setFontSize(12):setReadOnly(false):setSelectable(true)
    :setTextColor(0x000000):setVisible(true)

box_expr_doublecheck, error = D2Editor.newRichText():resize(300, 40)
box_expr_doublecheck:move(0, 150):setBorder(1):setBorderColor(0x43adee):setFontSize(12):setReadOnly(true):setSelectable(
    false):setTextColor(0x666666):setVisible(true)

-- To evaluate the expression
function run()
    local markup = matbox:getExpression()
    -- Math Box markup is "\0el {...}"
    -- Get everything between the curly braces
    local E = markup:match("{(.*)}")
    box_expr_doublecheck:setText("markup:" .. markup .. "   string:" .. E)
    local result, err = math.evalStr(E)
    if err ~= nil then
        show_error(err)
        return
    end
    box_result:setText("Result: " .. result)
end

function on.escapeKey()
    run()
end

function show_error(err)
    if err == nil then
    else
        box_result:setText("Error: " .. err)
    end
end
```

As can be seen, the annotations in proprietary markup language should be considered:

[image: Screenshot: fixed]

## Solution

These statements were the key:

```lua
matbox = box_expr:createMathBox() -- Math Box

-- ...

    local markup = matbox:getExpression()
    -- Math Box markup is "\0el {...}"
    -- Get everything between the curly braces
    local E = markup:match("{(.*)}")
    
    local result, err = math.evalStr(E)

-- ...
```

## General case

This is a general function to remove all occurances of markup characters `\0el {` and `}` inside an input string:

```lua
function delete_markup(strI)
    -- Remove all occurrences of "\0el {" and "}" inside string
    local strO = strI:gsub("\\0el {(.-)}", "%1")
    return strO
end
```